# How to check if an environment is a package namespace

Tags: r, namespaces, r-environment

I am looking for a way to detect if an environment is a package namespace. Desired behavior:

```
is.namespace(environment(data.frame))
## [1] TRUE
is.namespace(environment(ggplot2::ggplot))
## [1] TRUE
is.namespace(globalenv())
## [1] FALSE
is.namespace(new.env(parent = globalenv()))
## [1] FALSE
```

Comment: ?? I think you have a typo in your code. Should be `is.namespace(environment(ggplot2::ggplot))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is such a function. But for reasons that I don't understand it is named `isNamespace` instead of `is.namespace`.

```
> isNamespace(environment(data.frame))
[1] TRUE
```

More information can also be found in the related question here: [How to distinguish package namespace environment from other environment objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19937824/1953718)